# C# Socket is not responding in seperate thread

Tags: c#, sockets

Hello I am working on some code which envolves a hello protocol between two servers as a keep alive and to process files on the brother if a server goes down.

I run the same service on two different machines but on one machine it does not recieve and gets stuck on socket.recieve().

i have traced a wireshark and c# debug but the client sends but the server never responds, which is causing a problem for this feature

Thanks
Richard

```
    public static void Listen(ServiceController serviceController, Server server, List<Server> RemoteServers)
    {
        while (!serviceController.StopService)
        {
            if (server.ThisDevice)
            {
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(1);
             
                string response = "Hello Recieved";
                byte[] responsebyte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                try
                {

                    listener = new TcpListener(server.IPAddress, 11000);
                    listener.Start();
                    byte[] Bytes = new byte[256];
                    Listening = true;
                    while (!serviceController.StopService)
                    {
                        Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
                        int result = socket.Receive(Bytes);




                        ASCIIEncoding aSCII = new ASCIIEncoding();
                        string strres = aSCII.GetString(Bytes,0,result);
                        string stripped = strres.Substring(0, 5);
                        if (stripped == "Hello")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(stripped);
                            socket.Send(responsebyte);

                            string clientIP = ((IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                            ProcessHello(stripped,clientIP,RemoteServers);
                        }


                        socket.Close();
                    }




                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
              
                    listener.Stop();
                    Listening = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

```
public static void StartClient(Server server)
        {
            if (!server.ThisDevice)
            {


              
                TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(server.IPAddress.ToString(),11000);
                NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

                string msg = "Hello";
                string response = "";
                byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

                bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);
                try
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                   

                }
                finally
                {
                    // Close the reader
                    reader.Close();
                }
                tcpClient.Close();
         

            }

            public void StartClient(List<Server> servers)
        {
    
            _ClientStarted = true;


            var remote = servers.Where(s => !s.ThisDevice).ToList();
            Thread t = new Thread(() => ExecuteThreadedClient(remote));
            t.Start();
        }


        void ExecuteThreadedClient(List<Server> servers)
        {
            while (!_ServiceController.StopService)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    foreach (var server in servers)
                    {

                        TCPHelloClient.StartClient(server);
                        

                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(_HelloTimer);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException e)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(_HelloTimer);
                }
            }
            _ClientStarted = false;
            
               // Task.Delay(_HelloTimer).Wait();
        }

  public  void StartServer(List<Server> servers)
        {
            try
            {
                //var task = Task.Run(() => ExecuteThreadedServer(server), Token);
                Server local = servers.First(s => s.ThisDevice);
                var remote = servers.Where(s => !s.ThisDevice).ToList();
                Thread t = new Thread(() => TCPHelloServer.Listen(_ServiceController, local, remote));
                t.Start();


   
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                
            }

        }
```

Comment: That is not a different thread, are two executions of the same code in different machines.

Comment: Check sniffer results for [FIN} which indicates connection closed.  As use from cmd.exe on both machines >Netstat -a and see what status is indicated on both machines for the Port number.